# Is there any difference between "buy something from someone" and "buy something off someone"?

Tags: difference, phrasal-verbs

Could you tell me if there is any difference between *buy something from someone* and *buy something off someone*? For example:

> I **bought** these **off** the wedding photographer.

I've come across this in the 3rd episode of the 1st episode of the TV show *Narcos: Mexico*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Buy off" is much more informal, even casual, and is more common in some dialects than others. "Buy from" is standard English. There is no significant difference in meaning.

Answer (score 2):

You normally buy something ***from*** a retailer (someone whose *business* involves selling stuff).

If you buy something ***off*** someone, there's usually an implication that the person you bought it from *isn't* normally a "trader" AND/OR that you had to "persuade" them to part with the thing in exchange for your money (you "haggled").

This [potential] difference won't always apply, but it's worth pointing out that you'd probably never encounter ***I bought my Christmas turkey off a supermarket this year*** (that would *always* be ***...from** a supermarket*).

---

In OP's *specific* context, we're not told what "these" are (the things bought off/from the wedding photographer). But the speaker would be unlikely to use ***off*** if what he'd bought was *the pictures of his own wedding, taken by arrangement*.

Using ***off*** would be much more likely if he'd bought something "unexpected" for the context, such as some unusual camera lens filters that the photographer just happened to show him (and was persuaded to let go for a price).

Comment: Thank you for the great answer! Everything you said in your answer makes sense. Because the context is that an undercover police officer got the photographs from a photographer who had took the pictures at a wedding organized by criminals.

Comment: *...from a photographer who had **taken** the pictures at a wedding organized by criminals.* There's no doubt that as @David says above, *to buy [something] **off** [someone]* is more informal than buying it ***from*** them. And the usage distinction I've made *does* usually apply (it's just extra helpful how closely your context matches that distinction). But I wasn't able to establish whether this is purely a *British* thing, or if you'd find the same (quite "fine", but well-observed) distinction in American, Australian, Canadian,...